# How can I navigate between forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am a newbiest in c# and window form
i am doing a project and i meet some problem

1. how can i navigate forms within the window( i have a menu strip, when click it will show a item "Brand", so when i click it, it should open up within the window , i don't want something using the mdiparent/container, i have form1 and form2, then i put the menu strip in form1, which there is some thing inside form1, if use the mdiparent/container, the form1 content/thing will block the form2 )

2.i use the below code and the problem is i want to close the form1 which i click on " Brand" in the menu strip...but how???

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //  i put the menu strip in form1 design
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 Check = new Form2();
        Check.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You cannot just close the `Form1` as it is the main form, but you can hide it. Use `this.Hide()`.

```
private void Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 Check= new Form2();
    Check.Show();
    Hide();
}
```

**[EDIT]**

Not sure if this is what is asked. But...

There are many ways to implement navigation between forms, for example:

In `Form1`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Tag = this;
    form2.Show(this);
    Hide();
}
```

In `Form2`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form1 = (Form1)Tag;
    form1.Show();
    Close();
}
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you can say how to navigate back to Form1 from Form2 without creating a new instance of Form1(as its in hidden mode)

Comment: @Coder323 - I didn't realize that this is what is asked. Updated the answer.

Comment: I am sure the asker would have problem in returning back to the Form1 , just thought of helping.... Thanks for your code.....

Answer (score 4):

I think you should create usercontrols rather than different forms. Then you can add your usercontrols in your main panel according to the selection in the menu.

Initially something like below

```
this.panel.Controls.Clear();
this.panel.Controls.Add(new UserControl_For_Form1());
```

Once the user click some other selection in menu.

```
this.panel.Controls.Clear();
this.panel.Controls.Add(new UserControl_For_Form2());
```

If you really want to use the way that you are using at the moment. Below code will help.

Add a Form1 property for the Form2 and parse the form1 instance to the Form2 with its constructor.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private Form1 form1;

        public Form2(Form1 myForm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            form1 = myForm;
        }
    }
```

Show the form2 and hide the form1.

```
private void Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 Check= new Form2(this);
    Check.Show();
    Hide();
}
```

In form2 closing event now you can show the form1 instance which is in the form2 and close the form2.

Using of [MDI form](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mdiformstutorial.aspx) is another option for you.

Answer (score 0):

It has been 7 years since this question was asked but I wanna give an answer in case if someone is still looking for a solution. If you are using DevExpress, you can add Navigation Frame to your program. You can switch between different components such as GridControl, GroupBox and so on. So you dont have to create an extra form in order to navigate between forms.