# Visual Studio multiple GUI's in one project

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am creating a little game in C# Windows Forms with Visual Studio 2015. In this game I have a mainmenu with settings, exit-button, start,... and I have the game. Right now I have to make the GUI for the mainmenu and the game in the same window. Is there a possibility to make 2 GUI-Windows in one project? And if yes, how?

Comment: check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463142/how-can-i-navigate-between-forms

Comment: You can create UserControls and use them as GUIs in your Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new Form for every part of your game.
For example create a new Form for your menu and when you click "start" switch/open 
your game form at the same position.